# How to get instance of a specific running process in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

In elixir, if I invoke spawn to create a process but didn't store the process instance to a variable, how can I retrieve the instance of that PID again?

I know I can use Process.list() which will return all the processes running in the current node but is there a way to retrieve the instance of a specific PID?

Comment: The easiest way would be to either store the PID for future use, or name the process so you can reference it by that unique name (unique within a given node. Unless you registered globally, then it is unique across the entire erlang network).

Comment: so if I did not name my PID, then there is no way to retrieve it?

Comment: If you know the pid integer values, you can use `pid/3` to get the instance. E.g. `pid(0, 123, 4)`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be set a name for the process and retrieve it using [Process.whereis/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#whereis/1).